# Apple Watch: Localization of Storyboard not working

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

I enabled localization on the storyboard of my Apple Watch app:

[image: screenshot]

I added a label to my storyboard and localized its text through the .string-files. The interface preview correctly displays the according strings:

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

But when testing the app in the simulator or on real devices **the watch app always shows the english string** no matter if I select "German" as the application language in the scheme or "System Language" (devices' system language is german).

The iOS app on the other hand is behaving correctly.

Why does this happen? Is this method of localization not completely supported on watchOS yet? Do I have to manually set the label text through code using NSLocalizedString()?

I am using Xcode 9.3 and watchOS 4.3.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add Localizable.strings (Base) file in Watch Extension, it worked for me